# What is the difference between anonymous function and anonymous function with use in Php ?

Tags: php

I have recently go through these examples of anonymous function, but i am not very clear about it, what is the difference between them, why in second function
`use keyword` used and why first one return null and second one return 0:

```
<?php
$result = 0;

// first function
$one = function()
{ var_dump($result); };

// second function with use
$two = function() use ($result)
{ var_dump($result); };

$three = function() use (&$result)
{ var_dump($result); };


$result++;

$one();    // outputs NULL: $result is not in scope
$two();    // outputs int(0): $result was copied
$three();    // outputs int(1)
?>
```

Refrence link: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Did you try to run your example?

Comment: Are notices disabled? If so, activate them for testing purposes. `use` allows you to either reference or use a variable outside of the scope of an anonymous function. That being said, anon funcs have their own scope (including some super globals). This means you cannot access anything outside this scope. So, if you don't declare it, your variable will be used in the scope of the anon func, thus it's `NULL` (if you had turned notices on, you would get a notice for that). Accessing `$result` directly will allow you to **use**, but not modify `$result`. `&$result` passes the reference.

Comment: yes! i tried same result as mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This emits a *Notice: Undefined variable* and returns `NULL` because `$result` is not in the scope of the function, just like any function:

```
// first function
$one = function()
{ var_dump($result); };
```

This imports the value of `$result` to the anonymous function.  The value at this point is `0` so the function accessed by `$two` will always use `0` for `$result`:

```
// second function with use
$two = function() use ($result)
{ var_dump($result); };
```

This one uses `$result` as a reference to the actual `$result` variable, so when it is incremented before the function call it is `1`.  This also allows you to change `$result` from within the function:

```
$three = function() use (&$result)
{ var_dump($result); };
```

Another way to do get variables into your function is to define it to accept arguments and pass them in:

```
$one = function($var)
{ var_dump($var); };

$one($result);
```

Or with a reference:

```
$one = function(&$var)
{ var_dump($var); };

$one($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
    // first function
$one = function()
{ var_dump($result); 
};
```

must retrurn a Notice Undefined variable... if in php.ini notice is disabled return null

```
// second function with use
$two = function() use ($result)
{ var_dump($result); };
```

Return $result = 0

you increment $result++;

```
$three = function() use (&$result)
{ var_dump($result); };
```

return 0+1 = 1;

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. **Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct**. From PHP 7.1, these variables must not include superglobals, $this, or variables with the same name as a parameter.

So if you want to use variables from outside the function you pass them through the use construct.